# Reuse queries and their results in SQL Server via Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-function

I have a query that should be reused in many scenarios. This query receives some parameters.
Because it has to be reused, it can't be a stored procedure. So, it's created as a Function (not a View, because it needs some parameters).
This is the best approach so far, right?
The issue is that this query returns data that needs some post processing, i.e. reused in some other queries. I'm facing the issue about reusing them in other queries.

Example:
Function `GetMyFirstData` returns several columns, including a `FootNoteSymbol` column. I should create another Function (`GetFootnoteText`) to return the text (and some other details) about these footnotes.
How should I create the second function that will receive as a parameter the `FootNoteSymbol` (many) returned by the first function `GetMyFirstData`?

I'm avoiding Stored Procedure, because these results will most likely be reused in other queries.
Also, the `FootNoteSymbol` is also returned in many other functions, with different return structures (therefore I can't create a `TableType`, because the structure is not fixed - however `FootNoteSymbol` is common among all of them).

Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Functions that return data:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetMyFirstData
(
  @Param1 int,
  @Param2 int
)
RETURNS @Return TABLE
(
  Col1 int,
  Col2 int,
  FootnoteSymbol int,
  Col3 int,
  Col4 int
)
AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT Col1, Col2, FootnoteSymbol, Col3, Col4
    FROM MyData
    RETURN;
  END

CREATE FUNCTION GetMySecondData
(
  @Param1 int,
  @Param2 int
)
RETURNS @Return TABLE
(
  Col1 int,
  FootnoteSymbol int,
  Col2 int
)
AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT Col1, FootnoteSymbol, Col2
    FROM MyOtherData
    RETURN;
  END
```

Function that should get footnotes text:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetFootnoteText
(
  @FootnoteSymbol --this is the issue, how to reuse the footnotesymbols from the other functions
)
RETURNS @Return TABLE
(
  Symbol int,
  Text text,
  OtherDetail nvarchar(200)
)
AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT Symbol, Text, OtherDetail
    FROM MyFootnotes
    WHERE Symbol in --this is the issue, how to reuse the footnotesymbols from the other functions
    RETURN;
  END
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's your question? Please post some code.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod How should I create the second function that will receive as a parameter the FootNoteSymbol (many) returned by the first function GetMyFirstData?

Comment: Sounds like you should look at using table valued functions. I am guessing you have these as scalar functions. Using table valued functions with cross apply would make this pretty simple. It would also be faster than scalar functions (assuming they are inline table valued functions and not multi statement functions).

Comment: @SeanLange They are already table valued functions. The problem is that GetFootnoteText function can't cross apply, because sources varies (many other Functions generate the FooteNoteSymbol).

Comment: You have me at an extreme disadvantage here. You know what your tables look like, what the data is like, what the rules are and what the expected results are. I on the other hand can't see any of that. I can help point you in the right direction but there just isn't enough detail at this point to offer much advice.

Comment: @SeanLange I included some code if it helps to understand. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell (and I reference you to @SeanLange comment "You know what your tables look like, what the data is like, what the rules are and what the expected results are. I on the other hand can't see any of that.") you have a basic miss-understanding about how relational databases work.  To "solve" the problem presented here using standard relational database practices I would not split it up into multiple functions (as there is no gain there) instead I would create a SP that did a JOIN to get all the data you need.  Like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
(
  @Param1 int,
  @Param2 int
)
AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT MyData.Col1,
           MyData.Col2,
           MyFootnotes.Text, 
           MyFootnotes.OtherDetail, 
           MyData.Col3,
           MyData.Col4
    FROM MyData
    JOIN MyFootnotes ON MyData.FootnoteSymbol = MyFootnotes.Symbol
  END
```

You don't show how you use the parameters so I can't address that, but I can guess.  Let's say the parameters in this function are used in the where clause to limit the results. (Col1=@Param1 and Col2=@Param2) but in another case you have different limits (eg Col3=@Param1 and Col4=@Param2).

In this case the best way to do it is to make a view that is shared and limited in each SP.  I would not use functions as I see no value to them (and a high potential for problems as @RemusRusanu points out).  Like this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyData AS
    SELECT MyData.Col1,
           MyData.Col2,
           MyFootnotes.Text, 
           MyFootnotes.OtherDetail, 
           MyData.Col3,
           MyData.Col4
    FROM MyData
    JOIN MyFootnotes ON MyData.FootnoteSymbol = MyFootnotes.Symbol
```

with

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData1
(
  @Param1 int,
  @Param2 int
)
AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyData
    WHERE  MyData.Col1,
           MyData.Col2,
           MyFootnotes.Text, 
           MyFootnotes.OtherDetail, 
           MyData.Col3,
           MyData.Col4
    FROM MyData
    WHERE Col1=@Param1 and Col2=@Param2
  END
```

and

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData2
(
  @Param1 int,
  @Param2 int
)
AS
  BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM MyData
    WHERE  MyData.Col1,
           MyData.Col2,
           MyFootnotes.Text, 
           MyFootnotes.OtherDetail, 
           MyData.Col3,
           MyData.Col4
    FROM MyData
    WHERE Col3=@Param1 and Col4=@Param2
  END
```

I know that as a programmer who has worked in non-relational systems this is not intuitive.  However trust me, this will get you the best results.  This is how your server software expects to be used and over the years it it has been tuned to deliver you fast results using a view in this way.

Comment: Yes exactly right +1 -- A little less blunt than my answer, but gets to the heart of the user not understanding how relational systems work.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid this code repetition and mixing Footnotes details with the data itself. My plan was to retrieve the data using the functions, then use a unique function to retrieve the footnotes details.

Comment: @igorjrr - It does not "mix" the data -- that is only in the view.  This is what views are good for.  I understood what you were trying to do... I don't recommend it.

Comment: @RemusRusanu less Blunt? you should see some of my sweet answers haha. I was in a rush here. ;)

Comment: @Hogan I understand, but I'm going with Function since it requires parameter and the view would leave it too open. I've changed to inline table value function and I agree it's better since my need is basically a view with predefined parameters. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## DO. NOT. DO. THIS.

Reusing code is a noble goal, but SQL is not the language for it. There are many documented performance problems resulting from your approach. Some quick links [Query Performance and multi-statement table valued functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/10/28/query-performance-and-multi-statement-table-valued-functions.aspx), [Improving query plans with the SCHEMABINDING option on T-SQL UDFs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/12/596424.aspx) or [Compute Scalars, Expressions and Execution Plan Performance](http://web.archive.org/web/20180423042943/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/09/05/compute-scalars-expressions-and-execution-plan-performance.aspx).

I wish I had a good alternative for you, but I don't. Views are OK for query re-use. But attempting to compose SQL table value functions has always ended in disaster, in every engagement I've seen.

Don't do it.

At the very least stick to [Inline Table Value Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294(v=sql.105).aspx);

> - The RETURNS clause contains only the keyword table. You do not have to define the format of a return variable, because it is set by the format of the result set of the SELECT statement in the RETURN clause.
> - There is no function_body delimited by BEGIN and END.
> - The RETURN clause contains a single SELECT statement in parentheses. The result set of the SELECT statement forms the table returned by the function. The SELECT statement used in an inline function is subject to the same restrictions as SELECT statements used in views.
> - The table-valued function accepts only constants or @local_variable arguments

Comment: Yes exactly right +1 -- A little more blunt than my answer, but gets to the heart of the user not understanding how relational systems work.

Comment: Blunt? you should see some of my nasty answers haha. I held myself in check here

Comment: @RemusRusanu Do you ever recommend the use of table value functions? It seems that you are completely against it. By the way, I changed to inline table value function and included SCHEMABINDING, thank you.

Comment: @igorjrr I do recommend them sometime. What I specifically warned about is the attempt to build a 'framework' by composing primitive functions into more complex ones and so on and so forth, like you would build a library in a true 'programming' language. Ordinary in a programming language the most important criteria is readability, you write it for the next human to read it in 3 mo (it could be you). Few places need optimization and those can be explained.

Comment: But SQL is a data access language. Aside from inherent lack of language constructs (T-SQL clojures, anyone?) there is a bigger problem: any 'suboptimal' path gets amplified to a size-of-data issue. That 'suboptimal' query turns out to be much more than just 'sub' when put in production against 10 mil records. It will grind the entire application to a screeching halt.